# Azure Vnet Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, vnet

I want to restrict access to my Blob storage account (that contains images) to only my web site deployed on azure app service (S1 Service plan).
Below the steps I have done:

- I have create a Vnet and enabled the storage service endpoint
- I have restricted the access to the storage to the vnet just created
- I have added my web app to the Vnet (preview feature)

Unfortunately when I open the web site, images are not loaded because the below error : 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

I have try to look on internet but with no luck. also what I'm trying to acheive I guess should be very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a new version of the VNet Integration capability, you should make sure you meet the [limitation for new VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). Also, creating resources in some order for networking is very important. I suggest automatically deploying it using the ARM [template](https://github.com/ScottHolden/ARMExamples/blob/master/AppService-VnetNew-Storage/deploy.json).

Comment: I used the ARM template and it worked. I implemented it manually because in my region (north Europe) the Custom Template is not available

Comment: Glad this helps.:)